# How to run gulp task on save button on .css file?

Tags: gulp

I would like to run gulp task on save button on .css file to minify file. I have tried `gulp.watch` but it is not working.

Is there any other way to minify file on save button. Using Sitecore 9.1.1.

```
CLI version: 2.3.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more in detail? What save button are you talking about? Some button in Sitecore?

Comment: @JonKoivula, I am talking about `Ctrl+S` (Save any file through ctrl+s combination button)

Comment: Where are you pressing Ctrl + S`? Update the question with more information as the amount of information you have said is not clear. And how this is related to Sitecore?

Comment: I have already mentioned save button on .css file. What kind of information do you need ?

Comment: If this issue is not about Sitecore then this is a wrong place to ask question of this. You should go to stackoverflow instead of here. Here you should only ask questions regarding to Sitecore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

I have found two ways to resolve this issue.

```
1) gulp.watch
2) Bundler & Minifier Extension
```

**gulp.watch** :

```
gulp.task('minify:css',async function () {
    gulp.src('./css/*.css')
        .pipe(minifyCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('minified')
        );
});

gulp.task("watch",() => {
    gulp.watch("./css/*.css", gulp.series('minify:css'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('minify:css', 'watch'));
```

We need to click on `default` task on `Task runner explorer` to add the changes automatically in minified file.

I am using `gulp version 4` so using `gulp.series` .If you are using gulp version 3 then you can use this code

```
gulp.task("watch",() => {
    gulp.watch('./css/*.css',['minify:css']);
});
    gulp.task('default', ['minify:css', 'watch']);
```

Instead of

```
gulp.task("watch",() => {
    gulp.watch("./css/*.css", gulp.series('minify:css'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('minify:css', 'watch'));
```

**Bundler & Minifier Extension**

Found extension to automatically minified file by follow the steps in the below link
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier

We can add this extension in our project.
[image]

[image]